# Android ImageView disappears when using layout_above

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm using RelativeLayout and trying to make few buttons under the image. Why does the ImageView disappear, when I use `android:layout_above="@+id/likebutton"` in it? How to make it not disappear?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/listitem_shape" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/likebutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/likebutton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/like"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sharebutton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likebutton"
    android:background="@drawable/share" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_shape"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/likebutton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/likebutton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/like" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sharebutton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likebutton"
            android:background="@drawable/share" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this may help

Answer (score 5):

You are setting `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` so you can't use `android:layout_above="@+id/likebutton"`. In short **when you set some child view against the parent view, you cannot set other views relative to it.** Otherwise it won't reflect.

Comment: Could you provide some indication as to where to find documentation to this effect? Most of the time when you do RelativeLayout, you set something top or left or bottom, etc and then set other things relative to it. I don't see how you can have a view with nothing against a parent view.